# The idea behind using maven to compile source code

Tags: maven, build, automation, compilation

I am currently starting my adventure with Maven, and I actually don't understand the idea behind using it to automate compilation of my source code. For the time being I am working on small projects with up to 15-20 classes, and 1 main method in the "app" class. Could someone please give me the explanation with examples, when it's necesarry (or recommended) to use build automatation tool to compile the source code and how could I benefit from using it regarding source code compilation?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for different answers and I have a lot of work to do but since I've seen this question, as a Maven fanboy, I couldn't resist anymore and this below is my answer.

First of all, I agree with JF Meier which answered before me, but I think the answer can be improved.

IMO you have to consider Maven not just as a build tool, but as a multi-purpose tool which can help you to do very different things. The best 3, for me are:

1. Compiler. Obviously. Maven allows you to easily compile giant projects with a lot of submodules, even if some of these modules are interdependent one with each other.
2. Dependency and repository manager. Maven allows you to automatically download third party software and bind this downlaod to the build. This is immediately understandable if you think to framework or api dependencies from big corps (Apache found., Spark, Spring, Hibernate and so on ...) but it's really powerful in every enterprise context.

Example: you have a Maven project (let's say project A) which manages requests coming from a webservice and provides responses. This Maven project relys on another Maven project (let's say project B) which actually generates webservice jar and uploads it to a company repository. Well, when you have to add a field or a method to the webservice you just have to implements new software in project B, upload it the repo and change the version in Maven poms in both project A and B. Voilà: now **EVERY** developer of the company just have to "mvn clean install" project A to have the new version.

3. Sources and code automatic generator. Since Maven 2.x are available a lot of plugins (from Apache found. and others) which allow you to generate code and sources (tipically xml files) starting from little to none implementations.

Example 1: CXF plugin is commonly used to generate java classes from xml or xsd files.

Example 2: JAXWS plugin is commonly used to generate wsdl from SOAP webservice implementations or implementation starting from wsdl file.

Do you feel the power now?

-Andrea

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very specific, but I will try to answer.

Usually, you want your source code to end up in a jar or war, so that you can use it as a library or run it somewhere (e.g. on an application server).

Maven not only compiles the classes you have and creates the final artifact (jar, war), but also handles your dependencies, e.g. the libraries your project depends upon.